# Woocommerce Query Scaduled sale price

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a query that shows sale products only.

But i'm looking for a query that show just **scheduled products**, and don't show the products which sale time is expired.

here is my code:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'paged'          => $paged,
    'meta_query'     => array(
        array(
            'key'           => '_sale_price',
            'value'         => 0,
            'compare'       => '>',
            'type'          => 'numeric'
        )
    )
);

query_posts( $args );
```

How to do that?